# Выделить число из строки

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Здравствуйте!

**Вопрос:** как с помощью регулярных выражений в Java выделить число из данной строки?

> 0-30 : 250

Интересует число после двоеточия.

Число может содержать более трёх символов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String string = "0-30 : 250";
String[] parts = string.split(":");
int myNum = Integer.parseInt(parts[1].trim());
System.out.print(myNum);
```

Метод split() разделяет строку вокруг заданного регулярного выражения. В данном случае просто по двоеточию.

Далее вынимаем из второй части получившегося массива тот самый номер, предварительно обрезав пробелы (trim). И конвертируем её в число через `Integer.parseInt`